# Uploading with json causes missing template error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), is causing me a missing template error after I submit my form.

In my coffeescript js file I have the setup for dropzone:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false

dropzone = new Dropzone('#item-form',
  maxFiles: 1
  maxFilesize: 1
  paramName: 'item[image]'
  headers: "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  addRemoveLinks: true
  clickable: '#image-preview'
  previewsContainer: '#image-preview'
  thumbnailWidth: 200
  thumbnailHeight: 200
  parallelUploads: 100;
  autoProcessQueue: false
  uploadMultiple: false)

$('#item-submit').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  if dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0
    dropzone.processQueue()
  else
    $('#item-form').submit()
  return
return

dropzone.on 'success', (file, responseText) ->
  window.location.href = '/items/' + responseText.id
  return
```

Than I have my controller action, I want it to do this:

```
def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Than my form:

```
= form_for @item, validate: true, html: {id: 'item-form', class: 'form', multipart: true} do |f|
 = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'

    %main#image-preview
     Add a Photo
     .fallback
      = f.file_field :image, multiple: false

= f.submit 'Done', id: 'item-submit'
```

So now this setup allows me to submit the form without any images but when it has an image and I submit the form. It will give me this error in the missing template error:

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-14 03:35:29 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lZu8pjXdBY6wso5l1/B1lwgYDMkVmtRjCaPNBeK3uWy0mQItbv0bDaEZfujeEa2jt//S3qJ0f0fiWkIGC7uNFg==", "item"=>{"name"=>"dsdsds"es", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f4779ccd748 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151014-2664-16b2m09.jpg>, @original_filename="testimg.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[image]\"; filename=\"testimg.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "null"=>"", "commit"=>"Done"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]] 

   (46.1ms)  COMMIT
  Item Store (158.4ms)  {"id":29}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2115ms (Searchkick: 158.4ms | ActiveRecord: 47.7ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
...............
```

So I'm guessing I have to make a `json` file? But I don't know what that means or the setup you use. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template items/continue, application/continue with {:locale=>[:en], **:formats=>[:json]**, :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}.

The highlighted parts are the giveaway. The requested template is supposed to handle JSON, but the action doesn't have a template for a JSON template (and you haven't rendered any other way).

This is probably because you have

```
 if @item.save
   redirect_to post_continue_item_path(@item)
 else
   render :new 
   render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity**
 end
```

render :new before rendering the json. There is no new template and you are incorrectly trying to render twice. Lose the `render :new` line.

**Edit**

There are two issues. First, in the create action `@item.save` is failing, leading to the `render :new` line. Since in this case I'm assuming that you really wanted to return the rendered JSON, not a standard user form, you should remove the `render :new` line. This is redundant.

Secondly, you need to work out why your @item is not saving correctly by looking at your development.log. If you update it to `@item.save!` just for debugging purposes, this may provide you with some additional information with which to trace the fault.

**edit 2**

Based on your updated question, your @item is now saving. You are requesting the *show* partial, although it appears that this is not defined correctly or does not have an appropriate items/show.json.erb or other appropriate JSON partial. You will need to explore the documentation for drop zone to know what is needed

Comment: So I have to make a `new.js.erb` or `create.js.erb` file to handle this? What about a `continue.js.erb`? Rendering the page by json is completely fine, I'm just trying to get this to work correctly.

Comment: remove the render :new line and work out why your @item is failing to save. See my edited response

Comment: I totally revamped my question. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: My edit confirms that you need to generate a JSON response to drop zone. So it seems to have solved your original request. I think your new question is about how to create drop zone JSON, which the documentation should help you with. And send to be different to your original problem. If consider reviewing the documentation then starting a new post with surviving questions that may arrive.

Comment: My edit confirms that you need to generate a JSON response to drop zone. So it seems to have solved your original request. I think your new question is about how to create drop zone JSON, which the documentation should help you with. And send to be different to your original problem. If consider reviewing the documentation then starting a new post with surviving questions that may arrive.